# Is a leaky integrator the same thing as a low pass filter?

Tags: filters

The equation governing a leaky integrator (according to Wikipedia at least) is

$\frac{d\mathcal{O}}{dt} + A\mathcal{O}(t) = \mathcal{I}(t)$.

Is a continuous-time leaky integrator thus the same thing as a low pass filter with time-constant $A$, up to some scaling of the input?

Comment: Yes, but be sure to check the definition of time constant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A so-called leaky integrator is a first-order filter with feedback. Let's find its transfer function, assuming that the input is $x(t)$ and the output $y(t)$:

$$
\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + Ay(t) = x(t)
$$

$$
\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + Ay(t)\right\} = \mathcal{L}\left\{x(t)\right\}
$$

where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes application of the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). Moving forward:

$$
sY(s) + AY(s) = X(s)
$$

$$
H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{1}{s + A}
$$

(taking advantage of the Laplace transform's property that $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} \Leftrightarrow sY(s)$, assuming that $y(0) = 0$).

This system, with transfer function $H(s)$, has a single pole at $s = -A$. Remember that its frequency response at frequency $\omega$ can be found by letting $s=j\omega$:

$$
H(j\omega) = \frac{1}{j\omega + A}
$$

To get a rough view of this response, first let $\omega \to 0$:

$$
\lim_{\omega \to 0} H(\omega) = \frac{1}{A}
$$

So the system's DC gain is inversely proportional to the feedback factor $A$. Next, let $w \to \infty$:

$$
\lim_{\omega \to \infty} H(\omega) = 0
$$

The system's frequency response therefore goes to zero for high frequencies. **This follows the rough prototype of a lowpass filter.** To answer your other question with respect to its time constant, it's worth checking out the system's time-domain response. Its impulse response can be found by inverse-transforming the transfer function:

$$
H(s) = \frac{1}{s+A} \Leftrightarrow e^{-At}u(t) = h(t)
$$

where $u(t)$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). This is a very common transform that can often be found in [tables of Laplace transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms). This impulse response is an [exponential decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) function, which is usually written in the following format:

$$
h(t) = e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}u(t)
$$

where $\tau$ is defined to be the function's time constant. **So, in your example, the system's time constant is $\tau = \frac{1}{A}$.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it seems as transfer functions $\frac{1}{1+i \omega \tau}$ and $\frac{1}{\tau + i \omega}$ are different...

Answer (score 5):

The frequency response is the same, yes, but the application is different:

- With a low-pass filter, your signal is in the passband.  The cutoff frequency of the filter is set *above* the highest frequency you want to keep in your signal.
- With a leaky integrator, your signal is in the stopband.  The cutoff frequency of the filter is set *below* the lowest frequency in your signal.

[image]

Also, integrators are always first-order, while low-pass filters can be any order.

Comment: Same response except for the DC-gain...