# Problem with 1st order PLL update equation

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, estimation, pll, viterbi-algorithm

The output of a communication channel is given by:

$x(t) = \sum_n{a_n}h(t-nT)$,

where $\{a_n\}$ are BPSK symbols, $h(t)$ is the channel response, and $T$ is the symbol period. If there is an inherent unknown timing offset $\tau$ inside the channel response we will instead have:

$x(t) = \sum_n{a_n}h(t-nT-\tau)$.

Say we need to sample $x(t)$ at times $\{kT\}$ and we can detect the symbols using the shifted channel response $h(t-nT-\tau)$. In other words we do not wish to resample $x(t)$ to compensate for the timing offset but we can estimate $\tau$. An estimate of $\tau$ is given by $z_k = x_k \hat{a}_{k-1} - x_{k-1}\hat{a}_k$ such that $E\{z_k\} = \tau$, where $x_k = x(kT)$, and $\{\hat{a}_k\}$ are the decisions of a (Viterbi) detector. This is the $M \& M$ estimate.

The question is how to use this estimate to recursively update the estimates of $\tau$ in a 1-st order PLL sense since the following equation will diverge.

$\tau_{k+1} = \tau_k + stepsize \times z_k$

Comment: Maybe this presentation can help: https://www.gnuradio.org/grcon/grcon17/presentations/symbol_clock_recovery_and_improved_symbol_synchronization_blocks/Andy-Walls-Samples-to-Digital-Symbols.pdf

Comment: The problem is that unlike standard TED, here I do not have an estimate of the error $\tau_k−\hat{\tau}_k$ but only $\tau_k$.

Comment: You might consider a [leaky integrator](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/is-a-leaky-integrator-the-same-thing-as-a-low-pass-filter) to recursively average your $\tau_k$ estimate: $\tau_{k+1} = \alpha \tau_k + (1-\alpha) z_k$ for $\alpha \in [0, 1)$. The closer it is to $1$, the narrower the bandwidth of the filter.

Comment: Can it be $\tau_{k+1} = \alpha \tau_k + stepsize (1-\alpha) z_k$? Is this still a 1st order PLL with a transfer function of $\frac{1-\alpha z^{-1}}{stepsize(1-alpha)}$?